# code to draw a line taking length and angle as input from user in arcmap

Tags: arcmap

I want to make a command tool in arcmap. The purpose is to ask user to provide length and angle as input from a point(already selected by user) and then draw a line.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what version of ArcMap you are using?

Comment: This type of tool already exists. http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/tutorials/Editor_Ex2_2.htm